# Deformation retraction confusion

Tags: homotopy-theory

I am looking at the retraction deformations and one I saw is $r: R^n \to E^n$ and $$r(x) =  \begin{cases} 
      \dfrac{x}{|x|} & |x| \geq 1 \\
      x & 0\leq |x|\leq 1 
   \end{cases}
.$$
How does $r(x)$ go from $R^n$ to $E^n$ if $x$ is a number?

Comment: It looks like $x$ is a point with $n$ coordinates, not a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x$ is not a number, $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  However, $|x|$ is a number, which is why it's ok to say $|x| \ge 1$ and $0 \le |x| \le 1$.